# Date/Time in java

Tags: java, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert java string to Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object)

I have a form in which I insert a time in the form of : 10:19 as a `String`.  How can I convert this to the corresponding `Time` object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object

Comment: What happened to using Google these days?

Comment: @Gentleman no reason to downvote this. every question on stackoverflow can be answered by using a search-engine yourself and the level at which you can do this only depends on your experience, easy questions are not a bad thing i think

Comment: @eznme, I never downvoted this question or any question that requires search-engine searches. Neither did I request to close this question. Don't just assume that everyone that comments, do downvote or vote to close the question.

Comment: Sorry for posting. Will never do this again(on easy questions) since it seems it bothers you people.

Comment: @Sergiu, we are not against easy post. Many post, like the one you posted, have already been answered before. We suggest looking at **Related* * section (right-side of this post) to see if any of the past quesstions were answered. Also, Google search definitely can come up with results that fit your criteria1 :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the string into a Date object. You could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object.

Example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); 
Date time;
try {
    time = df.parse("10:19");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat that convert a string in a Calendar object or formats a Calendar object into a string

Answer (score 0):

See the next links:

[Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml

It was just Google.