# How to convert Date represented as a String to milliseconds?

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert java string to Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object)

In my Java code I have input String like `05.10.2011` which I need to convert to milliseconds.

So:

```
String someDate = "05.10.2011";
```

I have to convert to match milliseconds format.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing because `05.10.2011` doesn't mean anything without some timezone and time.

Comment: in this particular case, I'm receiving only string in format "dd.MM.YYYY"

Comment: Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date).getTimeInMillis()

Comment: There is no such format as `YYYY`, use `yyyy`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
String someDate = "05.10.2011";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(someDate);
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Comment: I think you mean `MM.dd.yyyy`

Answer (score 6):

You can use Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to easily convert to a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instance.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy"); // Month.Day.Year

Date d = formatter.parse(inputString);
long timestamp = d.getTime();
```

Answer (score 4):

use the **simpleDateFormat** which takes a **string** and converts it to **Date** then call the **getTime()** to get the date in milliseconds format

Comment: @JB-Nizet is correct, to adapt to your code replace **new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy")** with **new SimpleDateFormat("mm.dd.yyyy")**

Comment: You want "MM.dd.yyyy", not "mm.dd.yyyy".