# How to convert a String to a Date object for hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert a user-inputted String into hours, minutes, and seconds stored inside a Date object. Some code was borrowed from StackOverflow that uses a SimpleDateFormat object to parse the user input, but when it tries I get a ParseException.

```
System.out.println("Enter the start time of the event(hh:mm:ss): ");
String input = sc.next();
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("kk-mm-ss");
Date start = new Date();
try {
    start = f.parse(input);
} catch (ParseException e) {
   System.out.println("ERROR: Failed to parse start time.");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01:02:03"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at Main.createDialog(Main.java:78)
at Main.displayMenu(Main.java:44)
at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert java string to Date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object)

Comment: So how does `kk-mm-ss` parse `01:02:03`?

Comment: Kick Buttowski, the focus of the question was on the formatting of SimpleDateFormat's parameter.       @SotiriosDelimanolis kk represents hours (1-24), mm is minutes, and ss is seconds. The documentation is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: How does `-` parse `:`?

Comment: It doesn't because that was my error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at your format compared to what is been entered...

```
kk-mm-ss
01:02:03
```

See the difference?  Your format is expecting `-`, but you're providing `:`

Change `kk-mm-ss` to `kk:mm:ss`