# Convert String Date to integer and Get Month

Tags: android, calendar

I want to convert String Date to integer and get the month from that integer how can I do that??

For Example:
I have String Date as:

```
String date = "15-06-2016";
```

so how can I get month as:

```
06 as output in integer
```

Comment: Instead, You can have Java way to do this. this link may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse that to date to then get the number of the month, that conversion is not necessary (you could but is a waste  of memory and computational time).....

use regex, split the string and parsing the 2nd element of the array will get that directly...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "15-06-2016";
    String[] calend = date.split("-");
    int month = Integer.parseInt(calend[1]);
    System.out.println("the month is " + month);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using SimpleDateFormate Class you get only month in string than after you convert string to integer

String dateString = "15-06-2016"

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    String formated = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(date);
    int month =  Integer.parseInt(formated);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
        try
        {
            String date = "15-06-2016";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date d = sdf.parse(date);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(d);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); //YOUR MONTH IN INTEGER

        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this

it works for me.

```
String input_date="15-06-2016";
        SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date dt1= null;
        try {
            dt1 = format1.parse(input_date);
            DateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
            String strMonth=format2.format(dt1);

            int month=Integer.parseInt(strMonth);

            Log.e("date",""+month);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
        String startDateString = "15-06-2016";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date startDate;
        try {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Month "+(startDate.getMonth() + 1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```