# How to type in a date to a java argument

Tags: java

When I try to type a date in the part of the code where null is listed it wont work. They are date variables but I dont know how to just hard code a date. If i put 02/05/2018 where the null is. It will ask me to make it a string but I want it to go in as a date.

Just like how I randomly type in a customer or a number I would like to randomly type in a date.

DTO

```
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private long nmcAcctNo;
  private int hubId;

  private Date createTime;

  private Date updateTime;

  public CustomerDTO()
  {

  }

  public CustomerDTO(Long id, String name, long nmcAcctNo, int hubId, Date createTime, Date updateTime)
  {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.nmcAcctNo = nmcAcctNo;
    this.hubId = hubId;
    this.createTime = createTime;
    this.updateTime = updateTime;
  }
```

REST

```
// Your implementation should pull the actual list of customers from the database.
List<CustomerDTO> fakeCustomerList = new ArrayList<CustomerDTO>();
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(1L, "Customer 1", 1, 1, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(2L, "Customer 2", 2, 1, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(3L, "Customer 3", 3, 1, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(4L, "Customer 4", 4, 1, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(5L, "Customer 5", 5, 1, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(6L, "Customer 6", 6, 2, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(7L, "Customer 7", 7, 2, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(8L, "Customer 8", 8, 2, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(9L, "Customer 9", 9, 3, null, null));
fakeCustomerList.add(new CustomerDTO(10L, "Customer 10", 10, 4, null, null));
return fakeCustomerList;
```

}

Comment: what type is storing the date in your `CustomerDTO` ?

Comment: Its a Date however if i type in a random date like i did my customer or string it will not work and I dont want to have to make a variable for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object

Comment: No. I want to just type the date into the argument. Not create a variable. Is that not possible?

Comment: Instead of null try: new Date(), if you want current time(e.g, Tue Feb 06 00:32:38 2018). This way you don't create variable.

Comment: use   Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); instead of null and null for createtime and updateTime.

Comment: FYI, `Date` is a troublesome old class that is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes, in particular [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). For a date-only value,use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class: `LocalDate.of( 2018 , 2 , 5 )` for February 5th, 2018. For a date-time in your time zone , `ZonedDateTime.of( myLocalDate , myLocalTime , myZoneId )`. Search Stack Overflow as these have been covered many times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are typing a String object and not a Date one. What you need is String to Date conversion as follows.

```
String dateString= "05-02-2018";
DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
Date aux;
try {
    aux = dateFormater.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can pass the `aux` variable where you have `null`.

If you don't want variable creation you can follow other approach passing the following code instead of `null`

```
new GregorianCalendar(2018, 5, 2).getTime();
```